# What is a suitable probability distribution for monetary amounts?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, finance

In my Bayesian model, I have a random variable representing the amount of money received due to a user's click on an affiliate link on a website. There are several such links with different payouts; in my model I want to capture the uncertainty due to the unknown behaviour of the user. The amounts are typically in the range of 0.30 EUR to 0.80 EUR.

I am wondering: what is a suitable probability distribution for monetary amounts?

Comment: That would depend on characteristics we don't possess knowledge of. If there are several links with different payouts it will be a [finite mixture distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures) across the distributions of the payouts, but you haven't suggested what those might be and even if those are known, we have no basis here on which to assume relative probabilities for each, so those would need to be estimated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be no 'correct distribution' for this problem, as this involves too many unknowns  (silly humans, or perhaps there is one link paying 10$…). But what you are looking for is a parametrisation of the 'real' density. As there is not a single process involved (like a decay probability…) something like a single Poisson distribution will most probably not be sufficient. Have a look at 'folded' distributions like a [gamma-poisson mixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma.E2.80.93Poisson_mixture), which is much more flexible for fitting your real (dirty) distribution. Have fun, just search for distributions on google which look the most like yours and take it!